# Static approach or non static approach?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jersey

What should i do when i move my application to production. An application with Spring + Jersey + Hibernate.

Expected Server hits/second - 40 to 50.. Serverhits/min - 1000 to 1500. For this server load how should my configuration be?

TomCat
During production is it OK if i set these for tomcat

Initial JVM heap size: 256m
Maximum JVM heap size: 256m
Maximum JVM permanent generation size: 64m

If not please suggest.
P.S:  I'm hosting it in a cloud instance it is auto scaled. So no problem with RAM or CPU.

**Spring
A: Static architecture for DB operation.**

```
public class Booking {

        @Autowired // this is autowired by spring
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory; // Hibernate class

        @POST // this is Jersey (I guess this can handle 50 requests per soconds)
        @Path("/create")
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Response create(String json)  {
                ....
        DBHelper.insertIntoDb(booking, sessionFactory); // here i use static architecture. The reason why i used this is i dont want new object created for each request. (I tested with 10 request per seconds.. Will this be able to handle 50 request per second... or even 500 requests per second)
                ....
                return Response.ok(container).build();
        }
}

public class DBHelper {
         /**
     * Inserts the object in DB
     * @param object
     * @param sessionFactory
     * @return the saved object
     * @throws Exception
     * @throws ConstraintViolationException
     */
    public static Object insertIntoDb(Object object, SessionFactory sessionFactory) throws Exception, ConstraintViolationException {
        synchronized (sessionFactory) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction transaction = null;
            try {
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                if (object != null) {
                    session.save(object);
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                    transaction.commit();
                    return object;
                }
            } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
                transaction.rollback();
                throw new ConstraintViolationException(e.toString(), null, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.rollback();
                throw new Exception(e);
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

**B: Non static architecture for DB operation.**

```
public class Booking {

        @Autowired // this is autowired by spring
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory; // Hibernate class

        @POST // this is Jersey (I guess this can handle 50 requests per soconds)
        @Path("/create")
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Response create(String json)  {
                ....
        new DBHelper().insertIntoDb(booking, sessionFactory); // Non static
                ....
                return Response.ok(container).build();
        }
}

public class DBHelper {
         /**
     * Inserts the object in DB
     * @param object
     * @param sessionFactory
     * @return the saved object
     * @throws Exception
     * @throws ConstraintViolationException
     */
    public Object insertIntoDb(Object object, SessionFactory sessionFactory) throws Exception, ConstraintViolationException {
        synchronized (sessionFactory) {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction transaction = null;
            try {
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();
                if (object != null) {
                    session.save(object);
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                    transaction.commit();
                    return object;
                }
            } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
                transaction.rollback();
                throw new ConstraintViolationException(e.toString(), null, null, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.rollback();
                throw new Exception(e);
            } finally {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

**A: Static architecture**
*Pros:*
1) I'm not creating individual objects
2) So making sure my java heap is not filled up
3) Less work to Garbage collector
*Cons:*
1) Wrong object may be returned from insertIntoDd method... ( I guess this... But didnt face a single problem in Testing).

**B: Non - Static architecture**
*Pros:*
1) Surely correct data will be returned from insertIntoDd method
*Cons:*
1) I'm creating individual objects
2) Java heap may cause OutOfMemoryException
3) More work to Garbage collector

i'm totally confused.

What should i do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to have Single pattern used for your DB helper. So you will have sessionFactory inside single DBHelper class and it will private sessionFactory variable inside the class. This is more similar to your static approach but using proper pattern.

For memory usage ( better start with 250 MB min and max 1024 MB , Perm as 256MB ). Latter you can increase memory as your load increased.

For example as below..

```
public final class DBHelper {
```

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private static DBHelper instance=null;

// private constructor

private DBHelper() {

//initialize your session factory here

}

public static DBHelper getInstance() {

if (instance == null) {

instance = new DBHelper();

}

return instance;

}

public static Object insertIntoDb(Object object) throws Exception, ConstraintViolationException {

//do your coding to insert DB

}

}

public class Booking {

// so always it uses single insertDb method

DBHelper.getInstance().insertIntoDb(booking);

...

}

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't creating lots of objects, the only disadvantage of going non-static is the ~12 byte overhead for the ONE extra object you're using, and the only real advantage is the ability to easily modify it to make lots of independent instances of the service.

If you ever want to have multiple instances of the service without having to start up more little JVMs, I'd go with non-static. Otherwise, it probably doesn't matter.